# How to use sys headers in Windows (or find their MSVC counterparts)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw, jit

I was learning about to how to build a JIT compiler and stumbled across a piece of code (attached below) :

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


// Allocates RWX memory of given size and returns a pointer to it. On failure,
// prints out the error and returns NULL.
void* alloc_executable_memory(size_t size) {
  void* ptr = mmap(0, size,
                   PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                   MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  if (ptr == (void*)-1) {
    perror("mmap");
    return NULL;
  }
  return ptr;
}

void emit_code_into_memory(unsigned char* m) {
  unsigned char code[] = {
    0x48, 0x89, 0xf8,                   // mov %rdi, %rax
    0x48, 0x83, 0xc0, 0x04,             // add $4, %rax
    0xc3                                // ret
  };
  memcpy(m, code, sizeof(code));
}

const size_t SIZE = 1024;
typedef long (*JittedFunc)(long);

// Allocates RWX memory directly.
void run_from_rwx() {
  void* m = alloc_executable_memory(SIZE);
  emit_code_into_memory(m);

  JittedFunc func = m;
  int result = func(2);
  printf("result = %d\n", result);
}
```

Now before littering my terminal with error messages, I googled up MSDN for these functions and to my surprise, none of them turned up. These are apparently POSIX header files that are unavailable in Windows. My question is does MSVC alternatives to these headers exist?

I have installed Cygwin, but I get header not found error.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). What you're asking is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: And if you want to use this code on Windows, your best bet is *rewrite it all* to use Windows-specific functions.

Comment: A lot of unix APIs don't have a simple direct mapping to a Windows API.  mmap is one of them.  The closest equivalent is [memory mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping).  Completely different API.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I read the help pages of SO, but I didn't understand how I violated them. And I came here looking for the Win alternatives to these POSIX functions. I couldn't find them anywhere. How can I rewrite ?

Comment: The other alternative to trying to port unix code to windows is to just use Cygwin.  I've found most everything ports nicely to Cygwin and enables compiled programs to be shipped with the Cygwin DLLs to end users.

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow" (emphasis mine)

Comment: If you're on WIndows 10, use WSL (windows subsystem for Linux) and ditch any thoughts of using Cygwin.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson Windows 8.1 and 4GB with no admin rights to install WSL :(

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I asked for MSVC headers, not library. I think MSVC headers are made only by one company and will not result in flame wars which is the intention of the mentioned SO rule.

Comment: ***Now*** you no longer ask for a library. But there's still no way to directly build your code with only changing headers, As @selbie mentions, there just isn't any direct mapping between POSIX and Windows API functions. you must rewrite it specifically for Windows and the Windows API.

Comment: @AritroShome You will not be able to run OS specific code on a different OS without a library to port it. Either you would use a cross-platform library to make the functionality portable, or you have to re-write the code.

Comment: @selbie can I get cygwin dlls somewhere just to link ? like without installing the entire emulation layer ?

Comment: @AritroShome - It doesn't really work like that. You really need the whole Cygwin installation to build and link.  However, you can give end-users your executables and a handful of cygwin*.dll files to run on their own.  Maybe what you really want is to compile the unix code into its own cygwin linked DLL and do the rest of the code from windows.   Based on what you are trying to do - inject x86 assembly into a running program, I have a feeling you'll run up against a lot of other issues besides the mmap dependency.

Comment: @selbie where can I download cygwin as zip ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant . Do you know where the microsoft assembly instructions are found ?

Comment: @AritroShome: As selbie already warned, you need to understand what you're doing. You're not using assembly in `emit_code_into_memory`, you're using raw x86 binary code. Also, note that on modern Windows the equivalent of `PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC` is not possible (instead you toggle), and Control Flow Guard looks like it will stop this code as well. You'd need `SetProcessValidCallTargets` or Windows will kill off your JIT code as potential malware.

Comment: @MSalters what will be the proper way to build a JIT in windows ? Especially the codegen phases.

Comment: @AritroShome: That's way too broad for a StackOverflow question, let alone a comment. Also considering your earlier remark of "no admin rights", you may have unreasonable targets given your limitations.

Comment: @MSalters Win64

Comment: @selbie can you point to some resources so as to how I can use POSIX headers using Cygwin ? I have installed it correctly this time. But there is error : header not found.